# Creating Titanium Module project - error

Tags: titanium-modules

I am trying to write simple android module in titanium studio.. what is wrong with it?    I am using sdk 3.2.3. python 2.7. ndk r10.  T tried old ndk too but it did not help me.Here is my log:

```
Buildfile: C:\moduleWorkSpace\testingtest\build.xml
   python.set.exec:
  python.check:
 [echo] Testing for Python
 [exec] Python 2.7
init:
[mkdir] Created dir: C:\moduleWorkSpace\testingtest\build\classes
[mkdir] Created dir: C:\moduleWorkSpace\testingtest\build\generated
    process.annotations:
[mkdir] Created dir: C:\moduleWorkSpace\testingtest\build\generated\json
[javac] Warning: ti\test\ExampleProxy.java modified in the future.
[javac] Warning: ti\test\TestingtestModule.java modified in the future.
[javac] Compiling 2 source files to C:\moduleWorkSpace\testingtest\build\classes
[javac] org\appcelerator\titanium\view\TiUIView.class(org\appcelerator\titanium\view:TiUIView.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'value()' in type 'android.annotation.SuppressLint': class file for android.annotation.SuppressLint not found
[javac] org\appcelerator\titanium\view\TiUIView.class(org\appcelerator\titanium\view:TiUIView.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'value()' in type 'android.annotation.TargetApi': class file for android.annotation.TargetApi not found
[javac]      org\appcelerator\titanium\TiApplication.class(org\appcelerator\titanium:TiApplication.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'value()' in type 'android.annotation.SuppressLint'
[javac] Note: [KrollBindingGen] Running Kroll binding generator.
[javac] Note: [KrollBindingGen] No binding data found, creating new data file: org.appcelerator.titanium.bindings/testingtest.json
[javac] Note: [KrollBindingGen] Found binding for proxy Example
[javac] Note: [KrollBindingGen] Found binding for module Testingtest
[javac] Note: [KrollBindingGen] Generating JSON: file:/C:/moduleWorkSpace/testingtest/build/generated/json/org/appcelerator/titanium/bindings/testingtest.json
[javac] warning: The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[kroll.checkTiContext]'
[javac] org\appcelerator\titanium\view\TiUIView.class(org\appcelerator\titanium\view:TiUIView.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'value()' in type 'android.annotation.SuppressLint': class file for android.annotation.SuppressLint not found
[javac] org\appcelerator\titanium\view\TiUIView.class(org\appcelerator\titanium\view:TiUIView.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'value()' in type 'android.annotation.TargetApi': class file for android.annotation.TargetApi not found
[javac] org\appcelerator\titanium\TiApplication.class(org\appcelerator\titanium:TiApplication.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'value()' in type 'android.annotation.SuppressLint'
[javac] Note: C:\moduleWorkSpace\testingtest\src\ti\test\ExampleProxy.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[javac] 3 warnings
generate.v8.bindings:
 [java] Generating C:\moduleWorkSpace\testingtest\build\generated\jni\ti.test.ExampleProxy.h
 [java] Generating C:\moduleWorkSpace\testingtest\build\generated\jni\ti.test.ExampleProxy.cpp
 [java] Generating C:\moduleWorkSpace\testingtest\build\generated\jni\ti.test.TestingtestModule.h
 [java] Generating C:\moduleWorkSpace\testingtest\build\generated\jni\ti.test.TestingtestModule.cpp
 generate.bindings:
 pre.compile:
   js.compile:
    ndk.build:
 [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\moduleWorkSpace\testingtest\build\generated
 [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\moduleWorkSpace\testingtest\build\generated\jni
 [copy] Copying 11 files to C:\Users\MIRIAN~1.PER\AppData\Local\Temp\mirian.pertia\testingtest-generated
 [exec] Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:ti.test: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lkroll-v8    
 [exec] jni/Android.mk:35: warning: overriding commands for target `C:/Users/MIRIAN~1.PER/AppData/Local/Temp/mirian.pertia/testingtest-generated/KrollGeneratedBindings.cpp'
 [exec] Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
 [exec] Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the    jni/Android.mk:35: warning: ignoring old commands for target `C:/Users/MIRIAN~1.PER/AppData/Local/Temp/mirian.pertia/testingtest-generated/KrollGeneratedBindings.cpp'
 [exec] Android NDK:     current module    
 [exec] jni/Android.mk:38: warning: overriding commands for target `C:/Users/MIRIAN~1.PER/AppData/Local/Temp/mirian.pertia/testingtest-generated/BootstrapJS.cpp'
 [exec] jni/Android.mk:38: warning: ignoring old commands for target `C:/Users/MIRIAN~1.PER/AppData/Local/Temp/mirian.pertia/testingtest-generated/BootstrapJS.cpp'
 [exec] Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:ti.test: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lkroll-v8    jni/Android.mk:35: warning: overriding commands for target `C:/Users/MIRIAN~1.PER/AppData/Local/Temp/mirian.pertia/testingtest-generated/KrollGeneratedBindings.cpp'
 [exec] jni/Android.mk:35: warning: ignoring old commands for target `C:/Users/MIRIAN~1.PER/AppData/Local/Temp/mirian.pertia/testingtest-generated/KrollGeneratedBindings.cpp'
 [exec] jni/Android.mk:38: warning: overriding commands for target `C:/Users/MIRIAN~1.PER/AppData/Local/Temp/mirian.pertia/testingtest-generated/BootstrapJS.cpp'
 [exec] jni/Android.mk:38: warning: ignoring old commands for target `C:/Users/MIRIAN~1.PER/AppData/Local/Temp/mirian.pertia/testingtest-generated/BootstrapJS.cpp'
 [exec] Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
 [exec] Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the    
 [exec] Android NDK:     current module    
 [exec] Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:ti.test: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lkroll-v8    
 [exec] Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
 [exec] Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the    
 [exec] Android NDK:     current module    
 [exec] [armeabi] Compile++ thumb: ti.test <= ti.test.ExampleProxy.cpp
 [exec] [armeabi] Compile++ thumb: ti.test <= ti.test.TestingtestModule.cpp
 [exec] 'gperf' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 [exec] operable program or batch file.
 [exec] gperf -L C++ -E -t "C:/Users/MIRIAN~1.PER/AppData/Local/Temp/mirian.pertia/testingtest-generated/KrollGeneratedBindings.gperf" > "C:/Users/MIRIAN~1.PER/AppData/Local/Temp/mirian.pertia/testingtest-generated/KrollGeneratedBindings.cpp"
 [exec] make.exe: *** [C:/Users/MIRIAN~1.PER/AppData/Local/Temp/mirian.pertia/testingtest-generated/KrollGeneratedBindings.cpp] Error 1
 [exec] make.exe: *** Deleting file `C:/Users/MIRIAN~1.PER/AppData/Local/Temp/mirian.pertia/testingtest-generated/KrollGeneratedBindings.cpp'

 BUILD FAILED
   C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\module\android\build.xml:328: The        following error occurred while executing this line:
   C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\module\android\build.xml:281: exec returned: 2

Total time: 5 seconds
```

please help me with this.. thanks in advance.

Comment: you should update to 3.3.0, and use CLI it works like charm.

Comment: Yes, I tried it allready and it worked :)

Comment: i'm at Titanium 3.4.0 and Android NDK r10b, and I'm getting a very similar error. The project has the API level 19 set as the `android-platform`. Any idea how to fix this? (there are all the latest I could find)